# How to modify the actionbar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to modify my Actionbar to look like shown [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzvtB.png)   [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKWJN.png).

But I am having no success, can someone tell me how to go about it, the title is needed on the right and the font is also different

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you going to keep some action icons on it?

Comment: no action icons, just a logo on left and text on the right

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html ?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno what he wants, is not action bar at all. No app logo, no `back` icon, no actions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This is an example of how you shouldn't do it!!!** (see comments)

====================================================================

In `AndroidManifest`, add to your activity theme attribute with no Action Bar:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Add `RelativeLayout` to your layout, with blue background and `ImageView` containing logo on the right.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fakeActionBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#F00A"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    >

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_top"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why not use ActionBar.setCustomView()?

Comment: Brilliant, I have not tried it but you have suggested a very good concept. Thank you

Comment: @panini because action bar functionality is not needed as I understood. Blue stripe at the top of the screen is not a real _action_ bar since it has no _actions_.

Comment: @Salauyou what about if he is using the NavigationDrawer or something similar that interacts around the ActionBar? This solution won't handle these cases

Comment: I think your solution will work if you inflated the RelativeLayout, and then called ActionBar.setCustomView(relativeLayout) then it will work, however I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set action background after API 11.

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dummy_action_bar);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```